# Can a foreigner still cross the land border from Colombia to Venezuela in March 2016?

Tags: borders, colombia, land-borders, venezuela

Many Colombian-Venezuelan border control points seem to have been closed in the last year or so (at least for Colombian passports), but I have heard here in Colombia of travellers that have managed to get into Venezuela overland through the Cucuta checkpoint. Finding up-to-date information (last three months) has proved elusive. Can a foreigner still cross the land border from Colombia to Venezuela in March 2016?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it's complicated.

The safest border crossing is Puerto Carreño to Puerto Ayacucho by boat. Before you go in Colombia, do these:

1. DIAN (Colombian customs department) to make sure all your car papers are in order.
2. Venezuelan consulate to get a form with all the current requisites for crossing your vehicle ([find it here](http://cucuta.consulado.gob.ve/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=65&lang=es)). Later [the site which I am referencing from] learned that we needed two additional papers: a Venezuelan third-party insurance (easy to obtain, more on that below) and an invoice of the purchase of our car.
3. Immigration to stamp your passport.
4. SIJIN department of Police, to get a VIN rub of your car’s chassis number.

Then buy a Venezuelan insurance and go to SENIAT, Venzuelan customs.

Once done, boat over, then 100 kms to Puerto Ayacucho to get your passport stamped (three months for Europeans, free of charge).

Reference from [here.](http://www.landcruisingadventure.com/travel-information-on-venezuela-border-crossing-money-matters-roads-road-maps-and-more/)

Comment: I guess you understood something within the OPs question to mean "by car" where I assumed "on foot" - great answer

Comment: My end destination in Venezuela would be Mérida. It never occured to me of trying to cross the border so much down south as Puerto Ayacucho, but it's an idea. I am on foot actually so it complicate things. Buses from there to Mérida need to pass through Caracas, a 35 hour ride, tough but worth considering. How would you reach the remote area of Colombia bordering Puerto Ayacucho?